Can't make Vite SSR setup work in Dev mode
https://stackblitz.com/github/gihanrangana/vite-express-ssr-ts?file=README.md
So I got a project using this template. I am able to run "npm run build" and "npm run serve" on windows and on my server perfeclty. But "npm run dev" doesn't work on windows.
Im using a fresh install on this right now.
With npm version 10.8.3
and node v18.17.1
I'd love to be able to run it in a dev setup on windows so I can edit stuff without having to build it everytime :)
Whenever I do 'npm run dev'
I get this:
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\test> npm run dev

> vite-express-ssr-ts@1.1.2 dev
> nodemon --watch server --watch server.ts --exec tsx server.ts

[nodemon] 3.1.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): server\**\* server.ts
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[nodemon] starting `tsx server.ts`
node:internal/errors:496
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data, and node are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'
    at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:496:5)
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at throwIfUnsupportedURLScheme (node:internal/modules/esm/load:131:11)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:82:3)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at load (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Test/test/node_modules/tsx/dist/esm/index.mjs:2:1768)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:603:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:457:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:64:26)
    at #createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:480:17)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:434:34)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:79:21) {
  code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME'
}

Node.js v18.17.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

